# Using own database wrapper in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Recently I started learning some Symfony as a side "project". I know with Doctrine you can use MySQL. However, I got my own database class using PDO. How can I implement and use my own database class on Symfony? And in which folder should I place it?

I used the download from here: http://symfony.com/download and the tutorial from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html. I couldn't find anything about using an own database class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like any other class in php, or you can create symfony service for that class (you have everything about services in [symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html))

According [symfony2 best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html) you can put your class in any folder in AppBundle. But if you want to reuse your class on multiple projects you should put it on packagist, and instal it with composer.

But if just you want to learn symfony you should consider using doctrine, because most of the symfony projects are using it.